# How can I programmatically get all of a string's unicode entities to resolve themselves?

Tags: javascript, regex, security, unicode, xss

I'm trying to mitigate XSS.  How can I shield from this:

```
j&#X41vascript:alert('test2')
```

in the `href` of a link?

I've tried the following, but it just assigns the literal, unresolved value of that above string as a relative path of the href, not a proper `javascript:` href capable of triggering code execution.  I'm wondering how an attacker might be able to exploit this.

I've tried the following:

```
a = document.createElement('a');
```

and then both this:

```
a.href = 'j&#X41vascript:alert('test2')';
```

and this:

```
a.setAttribute('href', "j&#X41vascript:alert('test2')");
```

But both return `"j&#X41vascript:alert('test2')"` upon then querying `a.href`, not the desired (or undesired, depending on your perspective) `javascript:alert('test2');`

If I can get all the entities to resolve, then I can parse out all occurrences of `javascript:` in the resulting string, and be safe -- right?

The other thing I was thinking was that what if someone does `j&#&#X58;1;vascript:steal_cookie();`.  I mean, theoretically, they could have infinite levels of recursion, and it would all ultimately resolve, right?

---

## Edit: how does this code look?

```
function resolve_entities(str) {
  var s = document.createElement('span')
    , nestTally = str.match(/&/) ? 0 : 1
    , limit = 5
    , limitReached = false;

  s.innerHTML = str;
  while (s.textContent.match(/&/)) {
    s.innerHTML = s.textContent;
    if(nestTally++ >= limit) {
      limitReached = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return s.textContent;
}
```

Comment: Where do you imagine that these `<a>` tags, or the URLs, are coming from? Are you allowing user input to result in links on pages or something?

Comment: I think the only thing relevant here is that it's presumed hostile.  But basically, it's a sort of pseudo markdown that i'm parsing into html from JSONP tweet-feeds.

Comment: (and i don't control all the feeds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML/HTML character entities like `&#x41;` or `&amp;` are decoded *when the string containing them is parsed as XML or HTML*.  Typically, this happens when they are sent from the server to the browser as part of an HTML page, although there are other situations (such as assigning to `element.innerHTML` in JavaScript) which can cause a string to be parsed as XML or HTML.

Reading or writing to element attributes in JavaScript does *not* trigger XML/HTML parsing, and thus does not expand character entities.  If you write

```
a.href = "j&#x41;vascript:alert('test')";
```

then the `href` attribute of that `a` element will be `j&#x41;vascript:alert('test')`, ampersands and all.

What's important to note is that, whenever a string is parsed as XML or HTML, character entities are decoded exactly *once*.
Thus, `&x41;` becomes `a`, while `&amp;#x41;` becomes `&#x41;`.
It will *not* "all ultimately resolve", unless you're doing something silly like reading from `.textContent` and assigning to `.innerHTML` repeatedly.

Once the parsing is complete, it's *completely irrelevant* whether any character sequences in the output might or might not look like XML/HTML character entities — that is, *unless* you then take the output and feed it through an XML/HTML parser *again*.  (Doing that is very rarely useful, and usually only happens due to bugs such as assigning to `.innerHTML` when one should have assigned to `.textContent`.)

---

Anyway, looking at the comments, you say you're writing some client-side JavaScript code that's getting some untrusted data from a server you don't control, and you're worried that simply assigning the data to `.innerHTML` could allow XSS attacks.  If so, there are two cases:

1. The data you receive is meant to be plain text.  In that case, you should just assign it to `.textContent` and be done with it.
2. The data you receive is, in fact, meant to be HTML.  In that case you do need to undertake the difficult and laborious job of sanitizing it.  [This JavaScript HTML sanitizer from the Caja project](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer) might help.

Comment: Hey man, just noticed this little gem of an answer looking back through the thread.  Great explanation!! Clears up everything for me.  THANKS!!

Comment: Alright, really, what's happening is that I'm programmatically constructing an `HTMLAnchorElement` but then it's going into a larger string of HTML which will be assigned to my viewport element's `innerHTML` property.  So yes, I will be specifying the value of the link's `href` property in the manner you specified, but at the end of the day it will still just be HTML.  I've tested `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = encodeURI("j&#x41;vascript:alert('test')"); viewPortElement.innerHTML += a;` seems not to be sufficient.  So I guess I do end up with this recursion problem, still.

Comment: @adlwalrus: Can't you just do `viewPortElement.appendChild(a)` instead?  Stringifying DOM element objects and using the results as HTML may not produce consistent results, as you've noticed yourself.

Comment: That's a good point... Would you mind having a quick eye over my code when it's done?

Comment: Sure, I guess I could take a look if you post a link to it, although I won't guarantee I'll have anything useful to say. :)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the content is well-formed, you can use XML to parse it safely. Something like this, at least as a starting point ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GEFQ/)):

```
function getXmlDoc(s) {
    var parser;
    if(DOMParser){
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(s, "text/xml");
    } else {
        // IE
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(s); 
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}

var xml = getXmlDoc("<root>j&#x0061;vascript:alert('test2')</root>");
alert(xml.documentElement.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

​

However, I would probably just escape unsafe characters:

```
function safeEscape(s) {
    return s.replace(/[\&\<\>]/g, function($0) {
        switch($0) {
            case '&': return '&amp;';
            case '<': return '&lt;';
            case '>': return '&gt;';
        }
    });
}
```

You shouldn't  run into any problems with recursively escaped characters, as that's not allowed.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Two questions, however: 1) does it account for double-nested entities? 2) Do you have any thoughts on my appended pseudo-solution above?

Comment: @adlwalrus: Double-nested entities are perfectly fine, as long as you're not feeding the same string through an XML/HTML parser twice (which you normally shouldn't be doing). The whole point of escaping is that I can write "&amp;amp;" and it gets rendered as "&amp;", not as "&".

Comment: Are you aware that this is a URI, which will after sanitization become the `href` of an anchor? It could be `javascript:maliciousFunc(document.cookie);` which doesn't contain `&`, `<`, _OR_ `>`.

Comment: If you use the first solution and THEN put the result of the first solution into HTML, then yes, it could result in double-nesting problems because `&amp;#x006;` would resolve to `&#x006;` and then putting that in HTML would resolve to `a`. So two options: (1) Only insert the original code, and use the XML resolution to just check for a problem, and refuse to insert the code if there's a problem. (2) Use XML resolution twice and check for problems both times, then insert the result of the first resolution.

Comment: >  "(2) Use XML resolution twice "   

But then won't the attacker just make a triple-nested `&amp;`?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to mitigate XSS is to encode ALL untrusted output rendered to the screen using the appropriate encoding method method for the context the output will be in (HTML, HTML Attribute, CSS, JS, etc).

Even if you manage to solve this problem, there are likely other attack vectors using encoding that you have not thought of. Blacklist filter is rarely (if ever) the most effective way to protect your site.

<strike>I'm not sure what server-side language you are using, but there are likely encoding libs for it. [ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) is available for several languages and was built for this purpose (plus MANY others).</strike>

UPDATE: Since you need to use JavaScript for this, you may want to look at the [ESAPI Encoding Project (Reform).](http://code.google.com/p/reform/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/javascript) It has a JS version that looks like it will do what you need. I have not tested it, but if it works anything like ESAPI, then it may solve your problem.

To learn more about proper encoding per context, checkout the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the cheat sheet.  The context will be an HTML attribute, but that doesn't actually solve the problem I asked about: what if the `href`-to-be was a `javascript:` URI?

Comment: Then if it is encoded when sent from the server then it will not execute.

Comment: I don't control the server -- it's coming as untrusted content being relayed by a trusted JSONP-provider.