# Is there a better way to do this? (recursively resolving HTML unicode entities)

Tags: javascript, html, security, unicode, xss

I'm parsing an untrusted URI, but its URI-hood must be honored. I'm trying to protect against `javascript:` links, but I feel like I need to recurse on it, since you could have:

`javascriptjavascript::`

and after stripping out all instances of `javascript:` get back our old friend `javascript:` once again.

My other concern is analogously-nested unicode entities.  For instance, we could have:

```
"j&#X41vascript:alert('pwnt')"
```

...but we could also have:

```
"j&#&#X5841vascript:alert('pwnt')"
```

...though I seem to be doing it wrong (whereas a successful attacker obviously won't.)

```
function resolveEntities(uri) {
  var s = document.createElement('span')
    , nestTally = uri.match(/&/) ? 0 : 1
    , limitReached = false;

  s.innerHTML = uri;
  while (s.textContent.match(/&/)) {
    s.innerHTML = s.textContent;
    if(nestTally++ >= 5) {
      limitReached = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return encodeURI(s.textContent);
}
```

Comment: Are you scrubbing input on the client side? Such is better done on the server.

Comment: It's coming form a third-party server over which I don't exercise control.  It's a JSONP feed from the Twitter API.  I can assume that the JSONP wrapper is non-malicious and that it's faithfully relaying the content.  But the content must be presumed as hostile.

Comment: Gotcha. Just checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than specifying what you want to blacklist (e.g. `javascript:` URIs), it's better to specify what you want to whitelist (e.g. `http` and `https` only). What about something like this:

```
function sanitizeUri(uri) {
  if (!uri.match(/^https?:\/\//)) {
    uri = "http://" + uri;
  }
  return uri;
}
```

Comment: But that isn't what I want to do.  I'm trying to make it flexible by allowing ftp:// and mailto: URIs.

Comment: Then also whitelist those. Blacklisting is always a recipe for security problems.

Comment: Why? What I'm trying to do is mitigate XSS, not other protocols. It's the user's fault if they have silly protocolHandlers registered and installed on their system.

Comment: @adlwalrus - do you know that in all browsers, "javascript:" is the only scheme that will cause what follows to be executed as script? Or is it just the best known one? Unless you are 100% certain that there are no others (and I don't see how you can be), you are better off using a whitelist.

Comment: I'm as close to 100% sure as one can be about something like this.  I've spent the last three hours drowning in tabs reading about different variations on XSS.

Comment: Bzzt. `vbscript:`. Historically, `mocha:`, `livescript:`, some uses of `data:`. Blacklisting is a perennial source of fail, avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you already ask [almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331195/how-can-i-programmatically-get-all-of-a-strings-unicode-entities-to-resolve-the) before?  Anyway, my suggestion remains the same: use [a proper HTML sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer).

The particular sanitizer I linked to strips `javascript:` URLs automatically, but you can also set it up to allow only certain whitelisted URL schemes like Thomas suggests.  As he notes, this is a good idea, since it's much safer to only allow schemes like `http` and `https` which you *know* to be safe.

(In particular, whether a given obscure URL scheme is safe or not may depend not only on the user's browser, but also on their OS and on what third-party software they may have installed — a lot of programs like to register themselves as handlers for their own URL schemes.)